# About collision detection in GLM mesh

Tags: c++, opengl

i am new to opengl and glm , currently i am doing a class project in it, i upload two object cars as follows

```
void CARMODEL:: drawmodel_box()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(carx,cary ,carz);
    if (!pmodel1){
        pmodel1 = glmReadOBJ("Car.obj");
    }

    glmDraw(pmodel1, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_TEXTURE | GLM_MATERIAL);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void OpponentCarModel::drawopponentmodel()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    srand(time(NULL));
    opcarx=rand() % 7-3+(double)rand()/(RAND_MAX+1)*(1-0)+0;

    glTranslatef(opcarx,0,-20);

    if (!pmodel2){
        pmodel2 = glmReadOBJ("car.obj");
    }

    glmDraw(pmodel2, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_TEXTURE | GLM_MATERIAL);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Now , everything went fine upto now , now i come to the collision detection part , i am not sure how to do it here between two car, since i don't know their coordinate or vertices , so plz help..

Comment: FYI: There are two things called "GLM"; you should be specific that this is the mesh GLM, not the math GLM.

Comment: @user2080429 Please review the answers carefully, and up vote the ones that helped you. You can also click on the checkbox near an answer to select it as the official answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, but you can know exactly where the models are placed in the matrix because you call `glTranslatef()` before `glmDraw()` to place them there. Now, since you know the *x,y,z* coordinates of the models, you can start checking for simple collisions.

But if you are looking for a more real/complex collision detection you should open `glm.h` and check the definition of the `GLMmodel` structure because it stores everything needed to draw the model on the screen, including vertices information, normals, texture coordinates, and others:

```
/* GLMmodel: Structure that defines a model.
 */
typedef struct _GLMmodel {
  char*    pathname;            /* path to this model */
  char*    mtllibname;          /* name of the material library */

  GLuint   numvertices;         /* number of vertices in model */
  GLfloat* vertices;            /* array of vertices  */

  GLuint   numnormals;          /* number of normals in model */
  GLfloat* normals;             /* array of normals */

  GLuint   numtexcoords;        /* number of texcoords in model */
  GLfloat* texcoords;           /* array of texture coordinates */

  GLuint   numfacetnorms;       /* number of facetnorms in model */
  GLfloat* facetnorms;          /* array of facetnorms */

  GLuint       numtriangles;    /* number of triangles in model */
  GLMtriangle* triangles;       /* array of triangles */

  GLuint       nummaterials;    /* number of materials in model */
  GLMmaterial* materials;       /* array of materials */

  GLuint       numgroups;       /* number of groups in model */
  GLMgroup*    groups;          /* linked list of groups */

  GLfloat position[3];          /* position of the model */

} GLMmodel;
```

Comment: i put translatef for car motion but i don't know still it's position ,i am very new to it , plz help

Comment: The location of the car is determined by `carx, cary, carz`. What else do you need to detect a collision with this object?

Comment: please forgive my ignorance but i am still confused, for eg: isn't it like  if my initial coordinate of car is (x,y,z), then the translate  function translate it to (x+carx,y+cary,z+carz) ? then how can i know what is the value of x,y,z still?or is there any way to make initial coordinate i.e x,y,z to zero , so that i can use carx , cary,carz for collision detection?

Comment: If that is the case then you should start tracking `x,y,z` too, (store them in variables) so you always know what is `(x+carx,y+cary,z+carz)`.

Comment: how can i know inital coordinate , width , length of a object file uploaded by glm?? so that i can track x,y,z?? and how can i change it??

Comment: It seems like you have a lot of questions and it is a natural thing when you don't know what you are dealing with. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum so I won't keep answering questions in the comment section. You can ask a specific question and people will try their best to answer it. The problem is that the answers we can give you will lead to even more questions, and that's ok too, but you are only allowed one question per thread. Which means from now own you'll have to ask new question in new threads.

Comment: The initial coordinate of the drawing is `0,0,0` when you execute `glLoadIdentity()` because it resets the matrix. After that, you need to keep track of the values you pass to `glTranslatef()` yourself. All the other information related to the model is stored inside the `GLMmodel` struct.

Comment: No need to thank me, just up vote the answer. :) You can also click on the checkbox near my answer to select it as the official problem solver. By doing these things you will be helping future visitors like yourself.